# Expander Header not display group field content, only ItemsCount

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, lucene.net

i have a WPF DataGrid with a GroupStyle

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>

                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=citta}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander.Content>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

code behind:

```
var qq = (from a in q select new { formareg = a.Get("formareg"), citta = a.Get("citta"), conteggio = a.Get("conteggio"), parametro = a.Get("idcitta").ToString() + "|" + a.Get("formareg") }).OrderBy(x => x.citta).ToList();

                                ListCollectionView cv = new ListCollectionView(qq);
                                cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("citta"));
                                GrigliaDati.ItemsSource = cv;
```

All works fine but in Header of each group i see only ItemCount and not Path=citta.

What's wrong??

Answer (score 3):

Same as my earlier answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569614/wpf-itemcontrol-not-binding-correctly) question, it's because you bind to wrong field. You need to bind to group name and not to the field you group by. Try somethink like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
```

Each group is a [`CollectionViewGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.aspx) and it has its own properties that you can use when specifying group header.

Comment: OK Name is the name of propertie! i have seen a lot of answers but not yours! thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you must use "{Binding Path=Name}".  You cannot bind to another property.